# Permissions don't restrict access to NFS mount

Tags: permissions, nfs

We've got a RHEL 5.9 server with NFS mounted directories from a central NAS. There we've got a directory owned by `aird1(11055):app_dev(1101)` user/group with `rwxrwsr-x` permissions (i.e. *sgid* to app_dev). And finally we've got a process running as `grid(1001)` user.

The trouble is that the `grid` user can write into the directory although it shouldn't be able to. When I make a local test directory with the same ownership and permissions as the NFS mounted one I can't write to it, which is what I expect.

For some reason the NFS mounts don't fully obey the permissions. Here's an example:

```
$ ls -ldn /nfs/aird1/tmp
drwxrwsr-x 5 aird1(11055) app_dev(1101) 24576 Oct 17 13:21 /nfs/aird1/tmp
```

The directory is owned by `aird1(11055):app_dev(1101)` and has no ACLs attached.

When I attempt to create a file under my account it fails:

```
$ id
uid=20501(myuser) gid=1003(mygroup) groups=10(wheel),1003(mygroup)

$ ls -l /nfs/aird1/tmp/xyz
ls: /nfs/aird1/tmp/xyz: No such file or directory

$ touch /nfs/aird1/tmp/xyz
touch: cannot touch `/nfs/aird1/tmp/xyz': Permission denied
```

That's expected, but now the same as user `grid`...

```
$ id
uid=1001(grid) gid=1001(oinstall) groups=1001(oinstall),1002(dba)

$ touch /nfs/aird1/tmp/xyz

$ ls -l /nfs/aird1/tmp/xyz
-rw-r--r-- 1 grid(1001) app_dev(1101) 0 Oct 17 13:24 xyz
```

How come I was able to create the file?? There is no overlap between the UIDs and GIDs of directory ownership and either the `myuser` or `grid` yet with some UIDs/GIDs I can create the file and with some others I can't.

This is the record from `/etc/fstab`:

```
nas:/vol/... /nfs  nfs   rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,vers=3,timeo=600,nosuid,actimeo=0 0 0
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how the mount is being exported? This will be the contents of `/etc/exports` from the NAS.

Comment: I can't sorry. I don't have access to the NAS side. I'm not even sure it's Linux, may well be some expensive enterprise beast.

Comment: Can you do a showmount -e NAS? Run this from the client linux box.

Comment: Not much info in there, just the mountpoint matching fstab and a list of client hostnames (incl my nfs client)

Comment: Yeah that's what I expected.....

Answer (score 2):

NFS was originally designed to be used on networks with the same accounts (users, groups, and group membership) on all machines. If this isn't the case, strange things can happen. Recent implementations of NFS do have ways to remap user and group IDs between the client and the server.

Here's my guess as to what is happening. The directory is writable by group 1101 (which is called `app_dev` on the client). The server sees a request on behalf of user 1001 (which is called `grid` on the client, not that the server cares), so it attempts to write in the directory `/nfs/aird1/tmp` as user 1001. It so happens that user 1001 on the server is in group 1101, and therefore can write in this directory. Therefore the request is granted.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think so. The NAS is an appliance that has no idea about users and groups. IMO the permissions checks are done on the client, not on the server (but not 100% sure here).